# Is there a simplified article, video, or blog about bulletproofs?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, reference-request

I'm trying to learn about bulletproofs for my master "Enhancing Privacy in E-voting Systems", but the original paper was too hard for me. I also tried to look [at this](https://tlu.tarilabs.com/cryptography/bulletproofs-protocols/MainReport.html), but it was also too difficult. So, is there and article or a video or blog that explains bulletproofs on a beginner's level?

edit: i found [this](https://joinmarket.me/static/FromZK2BPs_v1.pdf) it is easy relatively and start from the basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this blog post](https://mitcryptocurrencyresearch.substack.com/p/mit-dcis-cryptocurrency-research-350) on the MIT Digital Currency Initiative's website super informative yet introductory. Hopefully, you find it helpful as well.